# Detect Compare-Window in Word 2016

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

Steps for the setting up the documents for the code.

1. Open Word 2016
2. Go to tab Review, Group Compare , use buildin Compare (documents 
   from filesystem)
3. In Compare-Window go to Review, Group Compare, use my own Compare Addin (documents from database)

The Code that causes the Error:

```
var compareDocument = this.thisAddIn.Application.CompareDocuments
    (OriginalDocument: originalDocument,
    RevisedDocument: revisedDocument,
    Destination: dialog.WdCompareDestination,
    Granularity: dialog.WdGranuality,
    CompareFormatting: dialog.CompareFormatting,
    CompareCaseChanges: dialog.CompareCaseChanges,
    CompareWhitespace: dialog.CompareWhitespace,
    CompareTables: dialog.CompareTables,
    CompareHeaders: dialog.CompareHeaders,
    CompareFootnotes: dialog.CompareFootnodes,
    CompareTextboxes: dialog.CompareTextboxes,
    CompareFields: dialog.CompareFields,
    CompareComments: dialog.CompareComments,
    CompareMoves: dialog.CompareMoves,
    RevisedAuthor: dialog.RevisedAuthor,
    IgnoreAllComparisonWarnings: true);
```

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMExpetion:'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has
>   returned from a call to a COM component'

This Error only appears if I call my compare-Addin from the buildin compare-window.

Compare Window

[image]

Add-in:

[image]

Comment: We need more information. It's not clear what kind of window(s) are present. Which version of Word is involved? Show us screen shots of the document(s) involved and indicate which is the window you're interested in. Also, it might help to have the code that generates this state of affairs ([mcve]). If we can't repro, we can't really help...

Comment: Thank you for the additional information - this is your starting point, and *the line of code* causing the error. But it's not a [mcve]: we have no idea what values are being passed to the method via `dialog`. And are you sure that both documents are available / can be opened that are specified by the variables? And why is this now about an error message, rather than finding out whether a window is a compare window?

Comment: The variables are boolean so they do not matter here, my code test the Open()-Method on these documents, if there is no error I confinue to remove any protection. The error only appears if my Addin is loaded from the compare window.

Answer (score 0):

ShowSourceDocument might help you. If the compare window is active this property will return Enum defined as follows :

- wdShowSourceDocumentsBoth 
  3
  Shows both original and revised documents.
- wdShowSourceDocumentsNone 
  0
  Shows neither the original nor the revised documents for the source document used in a Compare function.
- wdShowSourceDocumentsOriginal 
  1
  Shows the original document only.
- wdShowSourceDocumentsRevised 
  2
  Shows the revised document only.

In any other cases this property throw exception.

Calling GetType() is useless, because both ( the compare and the normal window ) windows are COM types.

There is a property Type. This property returns an Enum with two possible values : Normal or Template.

Comment: also, `application.TaskPanes(wdTaskPaneRevPaneFlex).Visible` returns `True` (unless it has been closed).